# Fiddlercore - Requested resource URL's are generic (OSCP-related) instead of actual resource

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, fiddlercore

I'm following [this blogpost](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.be/2013/08/implementing-webdriver-http-status.html) to try and see what Fiddlercore does.
The resulting console output, as per the blog, should be something like:

```
Requested resource from URL http://www.mozilla.org/
Requested resource from URL http://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/css/tabzilla-min.css?build=c2a3f7a
Requested resource from URL http://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/js/site-min.js?build=c2a3f7a
Requested resource from URL http://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/css/responsive-min.css?build=c2a3f7a
Requested resource from URL http://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/favicon.ico
Requested resource from URL http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/
```

However, in my case, the output has some rather generic URLs. I suppose there's something awry with my proxy, browser, ... settings somewhere? But I have no idea what.
I'm trying to write code that waits for a specific resource to load, so the output below is not really useful.

```
Starting Fiddler proxy
Fiddler proxy listening on port 6143
Requested resource from URL http://ocsp.digicert.com/
Requested resource from URL http://ocsp.digicert.com/
Requested resource from URL http://ocsp.digicert.com/
Requested resource from URL http://www.mozilla.org/
Requested resource from URL http://ocsp.digicert.com/
Requested resource from URL http://vassg142.ocsp.omniroot.com/
Requested resource from URL http://ocsp.digicert.com/
Requested resource from URL http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
Requested resource from URL http://ocsp.digicert.com/
Requested resource from URL http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
Requested resource from URL http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
Requested resource from URL http://clients1.google.com/ocsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.
First of all, I didn't have the certificate installed but was fixed with this code:

```
        if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertExists())
                {
                    if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert())
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
            }
        }

        if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertIsTrusted())
        {
            if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.trustRootCert())
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to install FiddlerCore's cert.");
            }
        }
```

Secondly, I had to define the SslProxy for Selenium to capture HTTPS:

```
        OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
        proxy.HttpProxy = string.Format("127.0.0.1:{0}", proxyPort);
        proxy.SslProxy = string.Format("127.0.0.1:{0}", proxyPort);
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue but resolved by switching to ChromeDriver and specifying ssl options:

```
    server = new Server(@"C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\bin\browsermob-proxy.
    server.Start();
    client = server.CreateProxy();
    client.NewHar("Test");
    var seleniumProxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = client.SeleniumProxy, SslProxy= client.SeleniumProxy };
    ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
    co.Proxy = seleniumProxy;
    co.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
    driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
    ...
```